# Separating row values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this kind of pandas dataframe output, columns are at the top row:

```
Gender,Name
Male, Matt 57
Male, Jack 42
Male, David 31
Male, John 28
Male, Tim 51
```

My goal is to get this kind of output:

```
Gender,Name, Age
Male, Matt, 57
Male, Jack, 42
Male, David, 31
Male, John, 28
Male, Tim, 51
```

How I can change the age value from the "Name" column to a new column which name is "Age"?

Comment: `Matt 57` is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.drop('Name', 1).join(
    df.Name.str.split().apply(pd.Series, index=['Name', 'Age']))

  Gender   Name Age
0   Male   Matt  57
1   Male   Jack  42
2   Male  David  31
3   Male   John  28
4   Male    Tim  51
```

This also gets you the same thing

```
df.drop('Name', 1).join(
    df.Name.str.extract('(?P<Name>\S+)\s+(?P<Age>\S+)', expand=True))
```

Or a step in the bizarre direction

```
df.assign(
    **dict(zip(
        ('Name', 'Age'),
        zip(*np.core.defchararray.split(df.Name.values.astype(str), ' ').tolist()))))
```

---

***naive time testing***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
split_values = df['Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df['Name'] = split_values.iloc[:, 0]
df['Age'] = split_values.iloc[:, 1]
print(df)

  Gender   Name Age
0   Male   Matt  57
1   Male   Jack  42
2   Male  David  31
3   Male   John  28
4   Male    Tim  51
```

Or even DRYer:

```
split_values = df['Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
for ii, col_name in enumerate(['Name', 'Age']):
    df[col_name] = split_values.iloc[:, ii]
```